# Issue with cURL in PHP, returning false regardless

Tags: php, curl

So I'm rather new to using cURL in PHP, I was told to use it for a task this week and it's been nothing but a pain, and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem no matter how hard I search.

What I am attempting to do is send a file to an upload directory on my hosted server from a remote portal manager that I have built. The file uploadhandler in the portal manager connects via curl to the remote destination and then the remote destination grabs the info and processes the file like normal. No matter what I've been trying though everything just throws back a failed response.

Here is the updated version of the code I am working with

**updates**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt(
    $ch, 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    array(
        'file' => 
            '@'             .$_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i]
            .';filename='   .$_FILES['doc']['name'][$i]
            .';type='       .$_FILES['doc']['type'][$i]
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo curl_errno($ch);
}else{
    echo "ok";
}
```

With all of this information set I am getting no value for `curl_error` but I get a value of `43` for `curl_errno`.

From what I have been researching, error `43` for curl is

```
CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT (43)
Internal error. A function was called with a bad parameter.
```

However all my functions for the `curl_setopt()` are put together correctly based on the info from php.net. So this is where I am now confused, because I have no idea what is causing this to happen. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: `if ($response === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`. never assume success when dealing with external resources. always check for failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: I just tried that and it literally returned nothing. I did something earlier and got an error number of `43`

Comment: There isn't such a HTTP error. Do you mean 403 forbidden?

Comment: it's a curl error, error 43 I looked it up and it means a bad function argument, I seem to be getting somewhere now.

Comment: well, you're doing a file upload, which means you'll have `$_FILES['file']`, and `$_POST['file']` will be undefined.

Comment: I have updated my question up top with new results